# Create folder on system32\driverstore\filerepository

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

One of my installation (itunes) is failing because of a path not found.

The question:

I need to create a folder in `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\` and copy to that new folder some files. I get access denied, I'm admin.. When I saw the privileges - only user `System` can write there but I've no idea how to acquire this user(I never created it).

Long story:

Itunes fails because it doesnt find the location of `usbaapl64.inf`. It looks for that file in `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usbaapl64.inf_amd64_neutral_ca639d07023cb608` which indeed doesnt exists, but I search where the installation get this path from (stored in some files/registry/device manager) and I didnt find where this path is store. I do have the location `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usbaapl64.inf_amd64_neutral_c111aaecb61e9a2b` so what I though was to create that location and copy the files to there. I really tried everything in order to fix that failed installation, this is the last resort.

Among things I tried (I scanned google and apple support, so I dont really remember the most) to install previous release, update apple usb drivers from the driver manager, split the apple installation to 3 (application support, mobile device and itunes), restart win between uninstall & install, clean the computer from left overs with verities of programs, clean the registry(plus clean it from anything that contain `ca639d07023cb608`), and I guess more things that I probably forgot...

Comment: you're approaching your problem incorrectly; you shouldn't be manually playing around with the driver file stores unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing.  First ensure you're using the right iTunes bit version for your OS (64-bit for 64-bit kind of thing).  Then go over this from Apple's support forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2231186?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: Been there, done that. I tried everything, and I know this is not the way to solve this. But, I just want to fix that, I'm on it for 3 days now. So all I care is to solve this, which I believe will.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you try the [ninite.com](http://ninite.com/) installer for iTunes?

Comment: Been where done what exactly?  Please edit your question to include everything you've already done/tried, including what the results were, to keep us from suggesting things you already did.  If you've really "tried everything", then there's nothing left for us to suggest. :)

Comment: use pnputil.exe to install the driver.

Comment: Been at the link you provided.. I edit my question, But I know what I want to do to fix that. I just dont know how to create folder there. I dont look for "the right solution", I believe my solution will work, I just dont know how to do it... if the pnputil will work I'll update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normal NTFS Permisions on folder `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\` are System - Full Control, and Everyone - Read & Execute.

I you **really** want to copy into this directory you can do the following:

- Right click the folder, click Properties
- Click the Security tab
- Click the Edit button.
- Now add your account and give it Full Control
- Click Ok
- Click Yes at the "Windows Security"-prompt
- At the "Error Applying Security"-prompt click Continue once and Cancel at the next
- Click Ok at the "Windows Security"-prompt

You can now copy files/folder into this directory.

To get control over all the other directories you could "Get Ownership" of this folder but that's not recommended. (you already have read access of those)

Comment: I just saw the error and clicked cancel, but the continue and then cancel - worked!

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this backwards.  @Rik is answer will work, but here is a better way.

create a folder c:\driver
copy all the driver files in

Go here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
Find DevicePath
Leave whatever is there alone but add

> ;c:\driver

The default is usually:  %SystemRoot%\inf
add the above gives you:
**%SystemRoot%\inf;c:\driver**

Then repeat here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

Unplug and replug your device
The **Found new hardware wizard** will launch find the drivers and load them into the directory you mentioned above automatically.